# What's the point of having mysql root password for root user?

Tags: linux, mysql, sql-server

As a root user on Fedora I have install mysql server with a mysql root password . Then I forgot the password and used `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` and bypassed the password , did some changes to the data and restart the server withou changing even the mysql root password !

Does this mean if someone has a root access can do anything without even resetting the mysql root password? ( at least if the mysql root password is changed we could know that something is fishy)

**In any case resetting the password or bypassing :**

Seriously What was the point of mysql root password for root user ?

Comment: Note that relying on "the password is changed" for auditing is not even remotely reliable. An advisary could change the password, do stuff and then change the password back to it's original value (without even knowing the password). All they need to do is replace the hash of the original password.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you have shell access to the machine.

If the `root` account was accessible without a password (which, by the way, is possible to set up IIRC) anyone who can connect to your MySQL instance could authenticate as `root`, effectively throwing entire security system out of the window.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean if someone has a root access can do anything without even resetting the mysql root password?

Yes.

> at least if the mysql root password is changed we could know that something is fishy

You already know that something is fishy because the database server *went down* for a brief moment.

> What was the point of mysql root password for root user ?

It's simpler than not having it.

Traditionally, MySQL has a root password so that you could do MySQL root stuff *without* having OS root access – you don't have to `sudo mysql`, you can be a normal user and run `mysql -uroot` and make the changes.

However, the password checking isn't done by the `mysql` client tool – it's done by the mysqld daemon, which just handles inbound connections and doesn't inherently know whether each connection comes from a mysql client that's being run as a normal user or whether the client is being run as root.

The daemon *can* know the client UID for local sockets, but retrieving that information takes additional code that needs to be implemented and tested (separately for every OS, e.g. Linux does it slightly differently from FreeBSD, and it's completely different on Windows).

In other words, it doesn't take any effort to ask all clients for password indiscriminately whether they're root or not, but it takes **additional effort** to implement a password bypass for root.

Both MySQL and MariaDB now do so by default (out of the box, MariaDB has a passwordless root account that is only accessible to UID 0), but because it's a change in security policy it cannot be applied retroactively to existing installations.